# Project 'cocoapods' isn't linked with Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

[image]

I am getting this error when I tried to open a sample project by name "cocoapods" in the Kotlin/Native samples.

Is there a way to resolve this error!

Answer (score 0):

If you see that error, just ignore and continue with your regular:
./gradlew build

or follow the instructions as stated in the Readme.md.

This is not a blocker!